# Align to center text below title

Tags: center

This is probably an easy question, but I am new to Latex and I cannot figure out how to center the author information below the title on the cover page of an article.

I am using the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{TITLE}
\date{June 2021}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \bigbreak
    
    \textbf{Name Surname}
    \\*Institution
    \\*Address Line 1
    \\*Address Line 1
    \\*Contact No: 
    \\*Email: 
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to modify this to center the author information below the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommended and the more LaTeX-y way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Title}
\author{%
  John Doe\thanks{%
    \TeX-\LaTeX\ Stack Exchange Institution\\
    The world wide web\\
    Contact number: 1234567890\\
    Email: tex-latex@se.com%
  }%
}
% \date{June 2021}% Uncomment this line to set the date.

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

but if you still want the author information to be centered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Title}
\author{%
  John Doe\\[2em]
  \TeX-\LaTeX\ Stack Exchange Institution\\
  The world wide web\\
  Contact number: 1234567890\\
  Email: tex-latex@se.com%
}
% \date{June 2021}% Uncomment this line to set the date.

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: 2]

Comment: Why the extra braces?  IIRC, the whole \author field is inside a tabular.

Comment: I am sorry, actually initially I wanted to change the size of that block, but I missed removing them afterwards. I'll remove now. Thanks.